# having issue with render ,everything becomes black

Tags: rendering

when i render at the end of rendering everything becomes black [image: ka]

Comment: What render engine do use, what lighting setup did you create, what should it look like?

Comment: StackExchange is a Q&A site which values questions that show you've made an effort towards solving the issue.
The [How do I ask a good question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
page from the Help Center may help you improve your question. Please try to describe what you've tried so far
and why this didn't give you the desired result.